# How do I disable Manifest in VisualStudio using C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'd like to have the UI elements switch to the Windows 95 UI for my program. But I am not sure how to disable Manifest in Visual Studio. Setting generate Manifest to off in the Linker doesn't seem to do it. Still new to this, not sure what the process is to shut it off.

Comment: Isn't it the linker flag `/MANIFEST:NO` documentation: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/manifest-create-side-by-side-assembly-manifest?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/manifest-create-side-by-side-assembly-manifest?view=msvc-170)

Comment: What project are you using? MFC?

Comment: I tried to use the linker flag to set Manifest:No, but it's not really changing the UI layout from Windows 10 when I test it with the debugger.
As for the project, I may be misunderstanding what you may be asking, but it's just an empty C++ project that I used as the base. With wxWidgets external dependencies loaded in.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Though I think I have to add the uxtheme.lib to allow HWND to be defined and accepted. I'll try and figure that one out on my own.

Comment: Glad to know `SetWindowTheme` is what you need! I converted the comment into an answer. If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snippet `SetWindowTheme(hWnd, L"", L"");    SetThemeAppProperties(0);` will disable visual style and use classic ui.